# Using definition of derivative to find $\sqrt{11\theta}$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

> $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(\theta+h)-f(\theta)}{h} \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; \textbf{(1)}$$ $$\lim_{z \to \theta} \frac{p(z)-p(\theta)}{z-\theta} \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; \textbf{(2)}$$

Can you show please how to find derivative of $p(\theta)=\sqrt{11\theta}$ using $\textbf{(1)}$?

My try:

$$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\sqrt{11\theta+h} - \sqrt{11\theta}}{h}= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\sqrt{11\theta}(\sqrt{h}-1)}{h}$$ 
Then I would rationalize, but I don't know how to proceed correctly. Please explain using $\textbf{(1)}$. Thanks.

Comment: The step $\sqrt{11\theta+h}-\sqrt{11\theta}=\sqrt{11\theta}(\sqrt{h}-1)$ is not right. Why?

Comment: @IanMateus I see, you can't factor $\sqrt{11\theta}$ out because there is no parenthesis. Thanks. But I still don't know how to solve this using (1).

Comment: You may remember that $\sqrt{11}$ is constant and that $\sqrt{\theta}=\theta^{1/2}$. There are other solutions, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiply numerator and denominator of $\dfrac{\sqrt{11(\theta+h)} - \sqrt{11\theta}}{h}$ by $\sqrt{11(\theta+h)} + \sqrt{11\theta}$.

Comment: ok, can you show more steps please?

Comment: @user436158 Only one step remains after that.

Comment: The answer is $\frac{\sqrt{11}}{2\sqrt{\theta}}$ and I don't see how to arrive at that from your work

Comment: @user436158 Did you multiply numerator of the fraction at least?

Comment: yes, \frac{11\theta+h-11\theta}{h(\sqrt{11\theta+h}+\sqrt{11\theta})}

Comment: $\frac{11\theta+h-11\theta}{h(\sqrt{11\theta+h}+\sqrt{11\theta})}$

Comment: Can you simplify the numerator?

Comment: yes, after simplification and evaluation as $h \rightarrow 0$, i get $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{11\theta}}$ but in the correct answer $\sqrt{11}$ is in the numerator

Comment: @user436158 Mistake is at the beginning. Should be $\sqrt{11(\theta+h)}$, not $\sqrt{11\theta+h}$. Sorry.